# C++ Constructors and static members

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I was trying something out and i don't know what is going on with the code. I have a class which has a static member and the default constructor and an overloaded one.

```
class Remote
{
public:
    static std::vector<Remote*> channels;

    static void interrupt() {
        for (Remote* r : channels) {
            r->ProcessInterrupt();
        };
    }

    void ProcessInterrupt() {
        std::cout << "ProcessInterrupt called.";
    };

    Remote(const int a) {
        std::cout << "Remote(const int a) called.\n";
        channels.push_back(this);
    }
    Remote() {
        Remote(1);
        std::cout << "Remote() called.\n";
    }
    ~Remote() {
        std::vector<Remote *>::iterator ch = std::find(channels.begin(), channels.end(), this);
        if (ch != channels.end()) {
            channels.erase(ch);
        };
    }
};
```

In main.cpp i declare two instances of the class Remote. What i now notice is that if i instantiate them with the default constructor the pointers are not added to the vector. Then i tried using the overloaded constructor and it does add it to the vector.

```
Remote r1 = Remote();
Remote r2 = Remote(1);
std::cout << Remote::channels.size() << "\n";
Remote::interrupt();
```

I would expect that since i'm calling the overloaded constructor it would still add the pointer to the vector. This, however, is clearly not happening.

Could anyone explain what is happening?

Kind regards,

Bob

Comment: I don't see any class here. Could you please provide [mcve]?

Comment: What do you think `Remote() { Remote(1); }` does?

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger and/or output some debug info when something happens. You'll be surprised.

Comment: @Chad : What i thought it would do is delegate it to the overloaded constructor. I just tried putting it in the initializer list and now it does seem to work. But i have no idea why the first method doesn't work.

Comment: @SSJVegetto becuase `Remote(1)` is called in the _body_ of the constructor, it's _not_ being delegated to, instead it's creating a temporary that immediately goes out of scope.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt : Thanks i just used the debugger and now i saw that you basically create a new Remote object, this 1 is added to the vector list but imediately goes out of scope. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yep, that was pretty obvious to me. However, the two mentioned techniques are much more important to master than getting this little detail right. ;)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt : Thanks for the tip. Would this also mean that in the body, that if i do: this->Remote(1); would actually work since then i'm refering to the current object right?

Comment: There is also rule of 3/5 which is broken.

Comment: @Jarod42 : Could you explain on how to do this? I have no idea on how to implement this.

Comment: @Bob: implement: `Remote& operator=(const Remote&)` and `Remote(const Remote&)`. For the first, `=default` seems ok currently. For the second, you probably want `channels.push_back(this);`. and there are also move versions:`Remote& operator=(Remote&&)` and `Remote(Remote&&)` to consider.

Comment: @Jarod42 : I'm not entirely sure on what these functions should do. I mean the copy constructor clearly makes a copy but does that mean you create copy of your object and return it? And how? And second, why wouldn't have to do anything for the move operator? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constructor

```
Remote() {
    Remote(1);
    std::cout << "Remote() called.\n";
}
```

Doesn't add anything to the `channels` vector.  `Remote(1)` in *this context*, is not a delegating constructor.

Try this instead:

```
Remote() : Remote(1) {
    std::cout << "Remote() called.\n";
}
```

See an example here:  https://ideone.com/ahauPV

Comment: This is correct, but you also forgot to mention something that's equally important. This is not the only reason why the static array may not get updated. For extra credit, update your answer to include the other reason.

Comment: aw dang, too much pressure.  You mean the temporary that updates the array but immediately goes out of scope (and therefore erases itself)?  If _not_, you'll have to give me a hint :)

Comment: Nope. Keep trying. Something else is completely missing from the class, that's also required in order to update the static array to account for every possible instance of the class that can possibly be constructed in any form, or fashion. Try to think of any other possible way an instance of this class can be constructed without having any of the existing constructors invoked (this should be a dead giveaway).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik : do you mean the copy constructor?

Comment: What else could I possibly mean?

Comment: Rule of 5 stuff yes -- copy/move constructors

Comment: @Chad : To be honest i have no idea on how to implement this in this case. Do you create a new object and return it or how does this work?